# codeigniter application doesn't come back with a response unless debug prints are included

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter-2

I'm experiencing a strange problem where some code I have that connects to a device over ssh and grabs logs no longer displays data unless I force it by include debug statements.

Here's the code in the controller:

```
public function logs()
{
    try {
        $data['logcontents'] = $this->device_model->get_logs($this->uri->segment(6), $this->uri->segment(3));
        var_dump($data['logcontents']);
        $data['Name'] = $this->uri->segment(5);
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage());
    }   
}// end logs
```

And here's the logic in the view:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2><?php echo $Name; ?> Logs</h2> 
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                          <th>Log Contents:</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <p>
                        <tr>                                        
                        <td><pre><?php print_r($logcontents) ?></pre></td>                                          
                        </tr>
                    </p>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

          </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

If I remove the var_dump() statement in the controller method, the web app will just sit there and not return / display anything. If I include it, i get the data dumped, and I also get the table with the expected results.

Can you point me in the right direction as far as how to troubleshoot this?  Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your action and try again? It's possible you have a scripting error in `includes/template` that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the printing value in loop?

```
<?php foreach $logcontents as $log {?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$log?></td>                                          
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```